# __stdcall in function paramater

Tags: c++, winapi, stdcall

does anybody know if is possible to add __stdcall (CALLBACK) in function parameter like this?:

```
void Function(LRESULT CALLBACK (*f)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM));
```

It gives me following error:

```
a calling convention may not be followed by a nested declarator
```

Any solutions?

Thx in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the calling convention inside the parenthesis.

```
void Function(LRESULT (CALLBACK *f)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is seen in the manual, for example [CallWindowProcW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowprocw)

> the *lpPrevWndFunc* parameter has the data type `WNDPROC`. The `WNDPROC` type is declared as follows:
> `LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC) (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);`

Thus, the correct syntax is (`WNDPROC` -> `f`)

```
void Function(LRESULT (CALLBACK* f)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM));
```